# Switch over UInt64 and uint

Tags: c#, byte

I have this `const` values:

```
private const uint val1 = 0xa1b3a3e4;
private const uint val2 = 0x12b3a4e4;
private const uint val3 = 0xaff3a3e4;
private const UInt64 val4 = 0x736e6f6f70000000;
```

I want to open my file and check if one of the above values exist at the first x bytes:

```
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)))
{
     UInt64 val = binaryReader.ReadUInt64();
}
```

**EDIT**

I read the first 8 bytes:

```
UInt64 val = binaryReader.ReadUInt64();
```

I need to verify this `val` is equal to `val4`.

This is the first bytes of my file using hex editor:

[image]

So as you can see this is the same value but still using the debugger i can see that:

`val4 = 8317708086210985984`

```
val = 288230376185266176
```

Why i have this differences ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to read in 5 x Uint32 and treat the Uin64 as a special case of 2 consecutive tokens?

Comment: Your machine, like almost all others, is little-endian.  So the little-end is first and your `val4` declaration is wrong.  It must be 0x000000706f6f6e73 to match the value you read from the file.  Albeit that I recon that "snoop" means something, it is not a number.

Comment: You can tell the debugger to display hex, makes the problem a lot clearer.

Comment: The decimal value  288230376185266176  In hex is 400000002000000     So I do not think your file pointer is where you think it is.  Also 400000002000000 does look like meaningful data as UInt64 but more like 8 bytes with all zeros excpet for two of the bits are 1.

Comment: So what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

The issue, as others have suggested, is that `BinaryReader.Read*()` reads data in little endian format, that is, with the most significant byte *last* rather than first.  This is consistent with the memory architecture of x86-class systems, where the most significant byte is stored in the byte with the highest address.

That is, when you declare

```
uint64 val4 = 0x736e6f6f70000000;
```

Then `val4` is represented in memory as:

```
00 00 00 70 6f 6f 6e 73
```

And when you call:

```
UInt64 val = binaryReader.ReadUInt64();
```

`val` is stored in memory as

```
73 6e 6f 6f 70 00 00 00
```

While `BinaryReader` does not provide methods to read big-endian data, a simple solution is to use extension methods to provide this functionality:

```
static class BigEndianBinaryReaderExtensions
{ 
    private static T ReadBigEndian<T>(BinaryReader r, Func<byte[], int, T> f)
    {
        int s = Marshal.SizeOf<T>(); // include System.Runtime.Interop;
        byte[] b = new byte[s];
        if (r.Read(b, 0, s) != s)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) // for correct behavior on big-endian architectures
            Array.Reverse(b);
        return f(b, 0);
    }
    public static int ReadInt32BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToInt32);
    }
    public static uint ReadUInt32BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToUInt32);
    }
    public static long ReadInt64BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToInt64);
    }
    public static ulong ReadUInt64BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToUInt64);
    }
    public static short ReadInt16BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToInt16);
    }
    public static ushort ReadUInt16BigEndian(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ReadBigEndian(reader, BitConverter.ToUInt16);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `BinaryReader.ReadUInt64BigEndian()` to get the expected result, as shown in the below driver:

```
static void Main() {
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(new byte[] { 0x73, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x70, 0, 0, 0 }, 0, sizeof(long));
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            ulong n = br.ReadUInt64BigEndian();
            Console.WriteLine(n == 0x736e6f6f70000000); // prints True
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The in-memory representation of the long `0x0011223344556677` is the bytes `77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 00` on many computers. That is, the bytes are stored in order from the smallest part to the largest part. Something has to be reversed here if you want to do this comparison; either reverse the array of bytes you are reading in, or reverse the order of the bytes in the constant.